# Using echo command as stdin in shell?

Tags: shell, echo

I was trying to search for a way how to use echo with a program I have written in C.

The program takes a word from stdin as input and I would like to know the command that will put whatever I type into echo into my program's input.

I was shown how to do this once but I forgot to write the command down and now I forgot it and cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Hi! Please have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! I don't get your point so far... What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use echo, you can do:

```
echo foo | a.out
```

Depending on your PATH, you may need to add `./`:

```
echo foo | ./a.out
```

(This is specifying a relative path to the program to be run, rather than letting the shell find it in PATH)

If you care about whitespace, you'll want to use quotes:

```
echo 'white    space matters' | ./a.out
```

Comment: Thank you William, echo 'white    space matters' | ./a.out was exactly what I was looking for!